# Raspberry PI crashes at startup. Why?

Tags: boot

Since my last re-installation of Raspbian, my RPi has been crashing at startup randomly. Meaning, most of the time, it usually takes two tries of rebooting my RPi before it launches to the log in screen. Between those two tries is failure and a reboot.

The first thing I've noticed is that half the time my Raspberry Pi crashes, it shows me that the "hardware clock is incorrectly set" followed by a line telling me that the "hardware clock" is set to one day in the future.

How do I change the hardware clock, then?

The next thing I've seen is that, the other half the time, my Raspberry Pi freezes while loading some files and blocks. The output here is random. Sometimes it freezes while loading 42344/654646 files and 1534655/2377915 blocks. Other times the numbers are different. What is my Rasp Pi even loading?

Why is it freezing?

Variables:

- Using RPi-3 model B running Raspbian Jesse
- Using the SD card that came with the package: Information on the card shown here:

On the backside: `9181AA DG 07SS2 Made in Taiwan`
On the front: `D42309 0480`

These are probably just registration numbers, though I just put them in to see if they might help.

On the front is also shows the Rasp Pi logo with a number 10 after it. beside the logo, there are words that say `Micro SD HC` which might be quite useful. I'm not an expert with Mirco SD's. I have no idea of which one might be the model.

- 25 volts are going in to the Raspberry Ri.

Comment: Which model of raspberry pi are you using ? What make and model of sd card ? What is the specification of your power supply (volts, amps)? Did you download the latest Raspbian Stretch with Desktop 2017-09-07 and flash the card with Etcher?

Comment: The edit is appreciated. I mean, it wasn't required, but thanks anyway.

Comment: As for the model, sd, raspbian, it will be provided in the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: SD card make and model should be printed on the sd card. Volts and Amps should be printed on the power supply. Did you download Raspbian 2017-09-07 and flash with Etcher?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: Oh, thanks codemike! I'll check it out when I leave a bit later.